# About private inheritance in C++

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, private-inheritance

Why cannot I privately derive a class from both a class and another class that the class being derived from uses as a base. So, I have the the following

```
class Money
{
public:
    void get() {std::cin >> amount;} 
private:
    float amount;
}

class Employee
{
public:
    void get() {std::cin >> lastName;} 
private:
    std::string lastName;
}

class Manager : public Employee, private Money  //money is used to store a wage
{
public:
    void get() {Employee::get(); Money::get();} 
}

class Executive : public Manager, private Money  // money is used to store additional bonuses
//warning :direct base 'Money' inaccessible in 'Executive' due to ambiguity  
{
public:
    void get() {Manager::get(); Money::get();}
}
```

I expected that in the `Executive` class `Manager::get()` would invoke `Money::get()` to save a wage, while the other `Money::get()` would save the additional bonuses.

As far as I know for now, private inheritance may be applied as a form of composition or when the base's interface should be hidden from outsiders, but is useful in implementing the class being derived. I undestand that in this particular case composition is all I need, still, I cannot understand what kind of ambiguity the compiler warns me about, for private inheritance does not allow neither outside classes nor subclasses of a privately derived class to take advantage of the relation

Comment: Your posted code is incomplete - where is `Compensation` defined?

Comment: Prefer composition over inheritance. A person HAS money. Few people ARE money.

Comment: Also, from a software-design-perspective: [don't use inheritance to model things like peoples' roles](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/436738/why-is-inheritance-bad-in-a-person-student-model) - but better yet: [don't think you have to use inheritance just because it's available](https://boxbase.org/entries/2020/aug/3/case-against-oop/).

Comment: @Dai, sorry, I misspelt. The class Money was called Compensastion when I ran the code, but I thought I should have called it Money for clarity

Comment: This has nothing to do with inheritance being `private`.   Even if the access isn't private, your `Executive` class can't do operations on `Money` (e.g. call `Money::get()`) because it has inherited twice - there are two (effectively unnamed) instances of `Money` in the structure of an `Executive`, and it is ambiguous about which one is referred to when doing (say) `Money::get()`.     There is no rule in the language that makes `Money::get(); Money::get();` refer to one base then another.

Comment: I see that `Employee` has a member called `lastName`. This is good. In exactly the same way `Manager` should have a member called `money`, inheritance is inappropriate here, irrespective of your technical difficulties.

Comment: In your world `Employees` don't have wages?

Comment: I ran into this situation, and Stroustrup told me to solve it like this:  `struct ExecutiveMoney : Money {};` then `class Executive : public Manager, private ExecutiveMoney {...};`, with `void get() { Manager::get(); ExecutiveMoney::get(); }` ... ambiguity gone.

Comment: @john, of course, they do, even in my world. But I was just experimenting with inheritance and wanted to know the rationale behind the limitation. The employees classes are just an example I came up with to ask the question so that it could be understood by those reading and trying to answer

Comment: @SjuTon Well please ignore my poor attempt at humour. It seems that me and a few other responders missed the specific intent of your question. If you have an abstract question like yours it's arguably better to just use classes X, Y and Z rather than anything from the real world.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you inherit from a class in C++, it means that your class contains that base as a subclass (e.g. `Money`), with all of its members.
When a derived class of that derived class inherits from `Money` again, it won't reuse that subclass, but get its own. What happens is:

```cpp
class Manager : public Employee, private Money
// means structurally:
Manager {
    Employee { ... }
    Money { ... }
    ...
}

// and
class Executive : public Manager, private Money
// means structurally
Executive {
    Manager {
        Employee { ... }
        Money { ... }
        ...
    }
    Money { ... }
    ...
}
```

The problem is that `Executive` now has two instances of `Money` in its class hierarchy:

- `Executive::Money`
- `Executive::Manager::Money`

This is the ambiguity that the compiler is warning you about.

#### Solution A - Composition over inheritance

If you really think about, it makes no sense that a `Manager` inherits from `Money`, because that would imply that a `Manager` *is an instance of* `Money`.
It would make a lot more sense if a `Manager` *had* `Money`:

```cpp
class Manager {
protected:
    Money money;
public:
    ...
};

class Executive : public Manager { ... };
```

Because `Manager::money` is a `protected` data member, a derived class such as `Executive` will be able to use it.

#### Solution B - `protected` inheritance

***DISCLAIMER:** DON'T USE INHERITANCE HERE, IT'S CLEARLY WRONG. BUT IF YOU DESPERATELY INSISTED ON IT, HERE IS THE SOLUTION:*

The most practical solution is to use `protected` inheritance instead.
The outside world still won't have access to `Money`, but `Executive` will:

```cpp
// protected inheritance makes Money available to derived classes
class Manager : public Employee, protected Money { ... };

// don't inherit Money again, use Manager::Money
class Executive : public Manager { ... };
```

Comment: Given that the code in the `Manager` class only has access to `Manager::Money`, and the code in the `Executive` class only has access to `Executive::Money`, it seems like there is no requirement for ambiguity here; either class could reference `Money` and there is only one superclass it could possibly be referring to.  Am I missing the underlying problem, or is the C++ standard just punting on implementing some disambiguation logic that could (in principle) be supported but currently isn't?

Comment: Thank you very much, you made it much more clear. But now I have another question. Assume I have made the inheritance protected and can access salary from Executive. But I want to add another Money subclass to Executive to hold bonuses. So there isn't a way to add bonuses to the Executive using inheritance one more time and all I can is to use composition?

Comment: @SjuTon Inheritance is more limited than composition. You need to use the right tool for the situation. This is why everyone talks in terms of is-a relationships for inheritance and has-a relationships for composition. Many situations are not appropriate for inheritance, such as wanting to inherit from the same type multiple types.

Comment: @SjuTon no, you cannot inherit from the same base class twice in the same derived class. It sounds like perhaps your `Money` class should be able to manage different accounts of money, or it should be called `Account` and then it would make sense for an `Executive` to have multiple accounts.

Comment: I don't think this answer should be even discussing the idea of inheriting from `Money` since that is clearly wrong, irrespective of the technicalities of how you might do it.

Comment: @john you have a point, but I still think the answer should contain it for those seeking an inheritance-based solution purely out of academic interest. I've swapped the solutions around and added a disclaimer.

Answer (score 1):

I use "otherpart" to replace the Executive::get()::Money::get()
so don't need to worry about derive, if you just want to add a string

```
#include<iostream>

class Money
{
public:
    // void get() {std::cin >> amount;} 
    void out() {std::cout << amount <<" " << otherpart<<std::endl;};
    virtual void get() {std::cin >> amount >> otherpart;};
private:
    std::string amount;
    std::string otherpart;
};

class Employee
{
public:
    void get() {std::cin >> lastName;}
    void out() {std::cout << lastName<<std::endl;};
private:
    std::string lastName;
};

class Manager : public Employee, private Money  //money is used to store a wage
{
public:
    void get() {Employee::get(); Money::get();}
    void out() {Employee::out(); Money::out();}
};

class Executive : public Manager, private Money  // money is used to store additional bonuses
//warning :direct base 'Money' inaccessible in 'Executive' due to ambiguity
{
public:
    void get() {Manager::get();}
    void out() {Manager::out();}
};

int main(void) {
    Executive compen = Executive();
    compen.get();
    compen.out();
    return 0;
}
```